# Why does a commentator say "she goes" when talking about a man?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've watched a video of the snowboarder [Ayumu Hirano winning the gold medal in Men’s Snowboard SuperPipe at the 2018 X Games in Aspen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmm6e-h4psw).

At 0:51 one of the commentators says:

> Awww, **she goes she goes she goes!**

And I don't understand why he says "she". Ayumu Hirano is a man. This is Men’s Snowboarding. What does "she" refer to here? And what does it mean? I suppose it means "He did it successfully", is it right?

For context, this is what they say from 0:38, if I understand correctly:

> Ayumu Hirano has a cab 1440 double we haven't seen yet.
>   If he tosses it in, his run will be right up to this -
>   Frontside 1440 double.
>   He's going!
>   Awww, she goes she goes she goes!
>   He does it!

On a side note, what does "If he tosses it in, his run will be right up to this" mean? That if he can make it the cab 1440 double will be the most important part of his run?

Comment: I'm hearing something that sounds like "He goes, she goes, she goes, she goes" ("he" for the first one, "she" for the others.") I think the announcer was really saying (or at least trying to say) "he" each time, but in his excitement he slurred the words "goes" and "he" together in an unusual way. Definitely very odd sounding, but one can hardly blame him for getting excited – that was astonishing!

Comment: Agree with @Nanigashi - take a look at "he goe**s, he** goe**s, he** goes". The combination of the "z" of "goe**s**" and the "h" of "**h**e" can definitely be slurred to produce a "sh" sound.